# Output type of Op Amps

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

What is the difference between differential, rail-to-rail, push-pull, open drain and single-ended output types of op amps?

Comment: Welcome to the site. [This one](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/operational-amplifiers) is a bit heavy but good start. [This one](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa011a/sloa011a.pdf?ts=1629086995122) have a little more theoretical back ground. I could not access [Khan Academy](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-amplifiers/ee-opamp/v/ee-opamp-intro&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjk3tXkrLbyAhXkRjABHed-BCkQtwJ6BAgDEAE&usg=AOvVaw1D1N7DOWv5iWMS0ulVTNwA) but supposed to be good.

Comment: Since you are new, read [this and links in that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270733/where-can-i-find-detailed-rules-and-guidelines).

Comment: It should be noted that Digikey is just a distributor and those classifications may or may not be very accurate. For example, one part listed as "open drain" is a current sense amplifier with a reference and comparator, not a simple amplifier. In other cases, there might just be an error in the entry. As always, check the manufacturer's latest datasheet from their website and any errata or app notes before  sourcing the part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Single-ended** is the typical op amp output type which has one output pin.
- **Differential** is for a [fully differential op amp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_differential_amplifier), which has two output pins. All op amps have a differential input, but these also have differential outputs.
- **Rail-to-rail** indicates that the output can swing from the positive supply voltage ("rail") all the way to the negative supply voltage. Most op amps are not rail-to-rail, which means that the output can only swing to within a few volts of the supply voltage "rails". "Rail-to-rail" can apply to either single-ended or differential output op amps.
- **Open drain** is not really a valid op amp output type -- this is likely for comparators which are being classified along with op amps. An ["open drain" or "open collector"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector) output is one where the output is the drain or collector of a MOSFET or BJT, respectively, and can only pull down the output voltage to a reference voltage by turning on the MOSFET / BJT. You need a pullup resistor to make the output go high when the MOSFET / BJT is turned off by the device. Since this isn't an analog output it does not apply to op amps, only to devices like comparators.
- **Push-pull** in this context is likely to differentiate a comparator's output type from an open drain -- this would be a comparator that can push the output high or pull it low without a pullup/pulldown resistor, unlike an open drain. All op amps can push the output high or pull it low so it really applies to all op amps and doesn't tell you anything about the op amp output.

The important differences for op amp outputs are single-ended vs. differential, and whether or not the output is rail-to-rail.

Comment: Note: a differential op amp also has a third input pin, which sets the common-mode voltage of the differential output